# Calcular fecha de vencimiento con JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quiero hacer un calculo en el que me muestre en un `input`cuantos días faltan para que se venza un seguro, un punto importante es que no tengo campo en la DB para guardar esta información, muestro los datos en una tabla por medio de un `while`con PHP, pero quiero mostrar el numero de días solo con Js (No se si es posible y no se como hacerlo).

Intente realizarlo con el siguiente script pero solo me muestra el resultado de la primer fila.

**SCRIPT**

```
function calculo(){

    var hoy = Date.now(); //Fecha de hoy 
    var fecha1 = moment(document.getElementById('SOAT_DESDE').value, "YYYY-MM-DD"); 
    var fecha2 = moment(hoy);

    document.getElementById('VENCE').value = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days');
    var dias = document.getElementById('VENCE').value;
    if(document.getElementById('VENCE').value > 335){
        VENCE.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        VENCE.style.color = "white";
    }
    else
    {
        VENCE.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        VENCE.style.color = "white";
     }

}
```

**HTML y PHP**

```
<body onload="calculo()">

<?php 
    while ($fila=mysql_fetch_array($rst_informe)){    
?>

<td><input value="<?php echo $fila['PLACA']; ?>" type="text" name="PLACA" id="PLACA"></td>

<td>
  <select name="GRUPO" id="GRUPO">
    <option value="<?php echo $fila['GRUPO']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['GRUPO']; ?></option>
</td>  
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $fila['TIPO_VEHICULO']; ?>" name="TIPO_VEHICULO" id="TIPO_VEHICULO"></td>

<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $fila['SOAT_DESDE']; ?>" name="SOAT_DESDE" id="SOAT_DESDE"/>-
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $fila['SOAT_HASTA']; ?>" name="SOAT_HASTA" id="SOAT_HASTA"/></td>

<td><input type="text" value="" name="VENCE" id="VENCE"/></td>

<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tu **select** tiene un error, no tiene el tag de cierre. Aparte, ¿Puedes agregar tu funcion JS **moment**?

Comment: Si, pero no afecta en nada el código.

Comment: Tienes varios elementos con el mismo ID en tu código, cuando ejecutas `document.getElementById` siempre tomará el primero que aparezca en el DOM

Comment: @amenadiel si me pudieras ayudar o dar una respuesta, por que precisamente necesito ayuda para realizarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Para calcular la fecha por **php**:

Ubica donde esta el **while** que usas para mostrar los resultados y justo después colocas:

```
<?php 

  $fecha_hoy= date("Y-m-d");  // fecha de hoy va antes del while para que la obtenga sólo una vez

function calcular_dias($fecha_hoy, $fecha_hasta) // esta función la puedes colocar en un archivo aparte, imagino tendras un archivo para todas tus funciones
    {
        $diferencia_dias    = (strtotime($fecha_hoy)-strtotime($fecha_hasta))/86400; // transformación para poder restar las fechas sin tener problemas con años bisiestos y demás
        $diferencia_dias    = abs($diferencia_dias); // Para garantizar que el número de dias de positivo (valor absoluto)
        $diferencia_dias = floor($diferencia_dias); // Redondeo hacia abajo para garantizar no contar 1 día de más      
        return $diferencia_dias; // retornamos el total de días que necesitabas
    }

  while ($fila=mysql_fetch_array($rst_informe)){  //despues de esta línea de tu código

    $fecha_hasta=$fila['SOAT_HASTA']; // fecha hasta proveniente de la bd

$diferencia_dias= calcular_dias($fecha_hoy, $fecha_hasta); //implementamos la función

?>
```

2) Colocas el resultado del cálculo de **días** en tu **input** de `name="VENCE"` así:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $diferencia_dias; ?>" name="VENCE" id="VENCE"/>
```

3) Luego colocas dentro de un **bucle en javascript** la **validación** de los colores que posees (verde o rojo) para que pueda recorrer y pintar todos los inputs y no uno solo como te esta sucediendo en estos momentos.

Tuve que hacerlo de esta forma porque posees otro error, el valor del **atributo "id"** de los elementos que necesitas es igual para todos (`id="VENCE"`). He aquí la solución

```
function calculo(){

  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].value > 335 && inputs[i].name=='VENCE' ){
      inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      inputs[i].style.color = "white";
    }
    if (inputs[i].value <= 335 && inputs[i].name=='VENCE' ){
      inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
      inputs[i].style.color = "white";
    }
  }
}
```

**OBSERVACIÓN:** Aunque no es necesario el paso que explicaré a continuación sería bueno que lo ejecutaras para que no quede esa mala implementación del campo **"id"** en tus formularios

La proxima vez considera por favor colocar un valor "único" como **"id"** a cada elemento **HTML** que tengas en tu formulario. Una forma sencilla de lograrlo en tu código sería crear un **"contador"** que te permita convertir tu `id="VENCE"` en VENCE1, VENCE2, VENCE3, etc concatenando la palabra vence con el contador que creamos. Este contador se incrementará automáticamente gracias a que lo utilizamos dentro del while.

Para crear esa variable que ofrece dinamismo al **"id"** utilizamos:

```
$unico= 'VENCE'.$i; // $i es un incremental que empieza en cero y aumenta de 
                    //1 en 1
```

y para poder colocar este valor dentro del **"id"** de cada input utilizamos:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $diferencia_dias; ?>" name="VENCE" id="<?php echo $unico; ?>
```

así

```
<body onload="calculo()">

<?php 

function calcular_dias($fecha_hoy, $fecha_hasta) // esta función la puedes colocar en un archivo aparte, imagino tendras un archivo para todas tus funciones
        {
            $diferencia_dias    = (strtotime($fecha_hoy)-strtotime($fecha_hasta))/86400; // transformación para poder restar las fechas sin tener problemas con años bisiestos y demás
            $diferencia_dias    = abs($diferencia_dias); // Para garantizar que el número de dias de positivo (valor absoluto)
            $diferencia_dias = floor($diferencia_dias); // Redondeo hacia abajo para garantizar no contar 1 día de más      
            return $diferencia_dias; // retornamos el total de días que necesitabas
        }

        $i=0; // contador

        while ($fila=mysql_fetch_array($rst_informe)){    
         $fecha_hasta=$fila['SOAT_HASTA']; // fecha hasta proveniente de la bd
         $diferencia_dias= calcular_dias($fecha_hoy, $fecha_hasta); //implementamos la función
         $unico= 'VENCE'.$i;
         $i++;
    ?>

    <td><input value="<?php echo $fila['PLACA']; ?>" type="text" name="PLACA" id="PLACA"></td>

    <td>
      <select name="GRUPO" id="GRUPO">
        <option value="<?php echo $fila['GRUPO']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['GRUPO']; ?></option>
    </td>  
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $fila['TIPO_VEHICULO']; ?>" name="TIPO_VEHICULO" id="TIPO_VEHICULO"></td>

    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $fila['SOAT_DESDE']; ?>" name="SOAT_DESDE" id="SOAT_DESDE"/>-
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $fila['SOAT_HASTA']; ?>" name="SOAT_HASTA" id="SOAT_HASTA"/></td>

    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $diferencia_dias; ?>" name="VENCE" id="<?php echo $unico; ?>"/></td>

    <?php 
        }
    ?>
```

Aquí el ejemplo de los **inputs** con el **javascript** sólamente para que observes la solución:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  if (inputs[i].value > 335 && inputs[i].name=='VENCE' ){
    inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    inputs[i].style.color = "white";
  }
  if (inputs[i].value <= 335 && inputs[i].name=='VENCE' ){
                inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                inputs[i].style.color = "white";
  }
}
```

```html
<!--inputs con nombre "VENCE" -->

<input type="text" value="200" name="VENCE" id="VENCE1">
<input type="text" value="455" name="VENCE" id="VENCE2">
<input type="text" value="677" name="VENCE" id="VENCE3">
<input type="text" value="212" name="VENCE" id="VENCE4">
<input type="text" value="355" name="VENCE" id="VENCE5">

<!--inputs sin nombre "VENCE" -->

<input type="text" value="355" name="otro" id="otro">
<input type="text" value="355" name="prueba" id="prueba">
<input type="text" value="355" name="novence" id="novence">
```

Eso es todo. Un Saludo!

Comment: Hola @Huskie de antemano muchas gracias por tu ayuda e interés, de pronto no me explique bien o no he captado el mensaje, pero busco que el script me muestre el numero de días que falta para vencer el seguro, desde el día actual(hoy) versus el día del `input` SOAT_HASTA, y que solo cambien el de color el `input` VENCE

Comment: Día de hoy vs SOAT_HASTA o campo SOAT_DESDE vs SOAT_HASTA?

Comment: Día de hoy vs SOAT_HASTA

Comment: hay la posibilidad de continuar la conversación en el chat?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71098/discussion-between-huskie-and-anderssonviveros).